# How to perform multiple seasonal adjustment using the package seasonal?

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a dataset with multiple series which looks the following (152 series):

```
   [overview of data][1]
```

I would like to use only a sub sample starting in the year 2011 and I have used the following code to create a subset and declare it as time series:

```
TSTotExp2011.ts<-window(TSTotExp.ts, start=c(2011,1))
TSTotExp2011.ts<-ts(TSTotExp2011.ts,start=c(2011,1), frequency = 12, class = c("ts"))
```

I then tried in R to seasonally adjust each time series. No matter how I framed it I am unable to get the desired results, e.g. the 152 orginal times series and the 152 seasonally adjusted time series

I would very much appreciate some help since I am new to R.